# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1

Tags: android, gradle

When I try to build my project with gradle wrapper I get this error:

```
./gradlew

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
         https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
     Required by:
         project :app

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

The same project builds OK in Android Studio.

I've already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188703/could-not-find-com-android-tools-build-gradle3-0-0-alpha7/4518891) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012681/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle3-0-0) but I'm using gradle wrapper version 4.1, have added google() repository and even tried setting `android.enableAapt2=false`. Any other tips? Thanks.

My root `build.gradle` file:

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My `gradle-wrapper.properties` file:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

UPDATE: Gabriele was right. I'd to add the repository also in the `app/build.gradle file`:

```
...
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
...
```

I guess that I was confused with this stament *"To add one of these libraries to your build, include Google's Maven repository in your top-level build.gradle file"* in [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html).

Comment: Are you trying to use fabric ?

Comment: Add the google() repo also in the buildscript block inside the app/build.gradle file

Comment: Thanks @GabrieleMariotti ! That was it.

Answer (score 23):

just wanted to leave an extra tip. When I installed Android Studio, I read somewhere that it was recommended to leave this configuration (with the '+' symbol)

**build.gradle (project)**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
        .....
        #more lines here
}
```

However, the project I am using uses an old version of gradle, and this line always requested the latest version. Took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, It resolves my problem but whats logic behind this? can you give a little more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Check your proxy setting on `Android Studio`

> File > Settings > Appearance

&

> Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy

Answer (score 0):

Here was how I resolved the issue.
Change the root build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

    .....
        //other codes here
    }
```