# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1. project from Github

Tags: android, gradle

I would like to open ten https://github.com/mukundmadhav/Wordpress-to-Android-app project in Android Studio. However, I have a problem.

I'm getting errors

> ERROR: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.1/gradle-3.0.1.jar
>   Required by:
>       project :
>   Add Google Maven repository and sync project
>   Open File

I tried to solve the problem with these methods

[Gradle 4.1 issue on latest android studio 3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47515676/gradle-4-1-issue-on-latest-android-studio-3-0-1/48646116)

[Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48523795/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle3-0-1)

[Could not find com.android.tools.build.gradle:3.0.0-alpha7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188703/could-not-find-com-android-tools-build-gradle3-0-0-alpha7/45188917)

However, nothing helped, does anyone know how to open this project?

Update:
Android Version 3.4.1

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be `google()` repo in repositories which searches plugins/libraries in google repository.

Also, version number for `com.android.tools.build` should match the Android Studio Version. For example: for Android studio 3.4.1, classpath dependency should be:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
```

Here is the modified code for build.gradle.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if `google()` is present in repositories in the top level build.gradle

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter() 
            google()
        }
    }
```

P.S - If you're using Android Studio 3.1 or higher, you should be able to click on `Add Google Maven repository and sync project` and allow Android Studio to make the necessary corrections by itself and resync the gradle.

Comment: I hava 3.4.1 version android studio I add maven. It doesn't work.